# Use LocalService or AlarmManager for a repeating and time consuming task

Tags: android, service

Currently, I have a stock market app. I would like to perform the following stock alert task code, even when my stock market app is being closed.

> Perform a list of stock quotes retrieval, through HTTP network protocol every 30 minutes. Notify user through notification bar if certain stock hits price alert.

I was wondering, should I use

- [LocalService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) with a long running thread, which sleep 30 minutes within an infinity while loop
- Schedule an every 30 minutes task to [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

My concern is

1. If I am using `LocalService`, let say the user kill the stock market app explicitly through `Settings -> Apps -> Running -> Stop`, the service will be killed as well. The stock alert task code will no longer running.
2. Can `AlarmManager` ensure the stock alert task code will always executed even user kills the stock market app? However, is it suitable for `AlarmManager` to execute such time consuming task?

I was wondering, should I use `LocalService` or `AlarmManager` in my case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use AlarmManager to send a pending intent to start the service for every 30mins. And the service does its job and calls `stopSelf()`. Keeping service idle for very long time is waste of system resources.